# tkinter - passar argumento para a função

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
class Tela:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.fontePadrao = ("Arial", "10")
        master = Toplevel(self.root)
        self.primeiroContainer = Frame(master)
        self.primeiroContainer["pady"] = 10
        self.primeiroContainer["padx"] = 30
        self.primeiroContainer.pack()

        self.segundoContainer = Frame(master)
        self.segundoContainer["pady"] = 10
        self.segundoContainer.pack()

        self.titulo = Label(self.primeiroContainer, text="Client")
        self.titulo["font"] = ("Arial", "10", "bold")
        self.titulo.pack()

        self.btnMessage = Button(self.segundoContainer)
        self.btnMessage.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.btnMessage["text"] = "imprimir mensagem"
        self.btnMessage["font"] = ("Calibri", "10")
        self.btnMessage["width"] = 15
        self.btnMessage["command"] = self.printMessage("Olá!")
        self.btnMessage.pack()

    def printMessage(message):
        print(message)
```

Mas não consigo passar o argumento para a função... como devo fazer?

Comment: Qual função você se refere?

Comment: Me refiro a função printMessage()

Comment: Ela é um método, por isso ela não deveria receber `self` como primeiro parâmetro, assim como fez em `__init__`?

Comment: Ops, eu vi isso agora também, e corrigi. Mas o meu problema aqui é que da forma como está, quando o programa executa ele já chama essa função. Mas quero que ela seja chamada apenas quando eu clicar no botão. Sem passar os parametros e deixando uma mensagem chumbada la, ele funciona. ai na hora de chamlar la pelo botão, eu coloca apenas printMessage, sem os parênteses.

Answer (score 1):

Você fez

```
self.btnMessage["command"] = self.printMessage("Olá!")
```

Que basicamente está atribuindo o **retorno** da função `self.printMessage` como comando. Como ela não possui retorno, será atribuído o valor `None`. Porém, é esperado que você passe como comando um objeto chamável e a ideia é que quando esse objeto for chamado a mensagem seja exibida.

Para tal, você pode utilizar a função `functools.partial` que cria um novo objeto chamável e que você consegue definir os valores dos parâmetros:

```
from functools import partial

...
self.printMessage = partial(self.printMessage, "Olá!")
```

Assim, o retorno de `partial(self.printMessage, "Olá!")` será um objeto chamável que quando chamado executará a função `self.printMessage` passando a *string* `"Olá!"` como parâmetro.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema.
colocando um lambda na linha

```
self.btnMessage["command"] = lambda: self.printMessage("Olá!")
```